# What can I change/investigate where the install does not complete?

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, installation, cpu

I have already successfully installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop and it works fine.

I attempted to get my desktop PC to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu but found that neither the 32 or 64 bit install images will boot/install successfully.

The startup script locks on 'initializing core #2' (or 1 or 3).. once I saw it say 'ok' at the end but it still locks there.

I have tried to change the boot sequence by inserting 'debug' and 'acpi-off' into txt.cfg in both isolinux and syslinux folders but no changes were obvious during the boot.. as far as it got.

The pc is built with an abit IP35 motherboard and nvidia 8600GT gfx card.

Does anyone have any suggestion of what else I can change to get the install working?

Comment: Did you update the Bios just in case. And also tried putting another hard drive in there and testing with a live cd (Without the actual hard drive you wanted to install it in.)

Comment: @cyrex - the bios is as up to date as i can get it as it is an abit motherboard and they stopped trading a couple of years ago.
i think the DVD drive is broken so i can only boot from usb drive at present.. the hard drives are fine, they are running windows without any issue..
i've also now attempted to use wubi which got through the install but then wouldn't boot.

Comment: Do the following (Just to humor me) get ANOTHER hard drive, an old one or a shared from a friend and connect it to the PC but leave it alone with no other hard drives connected also. Only the old one should be connected. Remove ANYHING else connected and leave only the CPU, MotherBoard, Memory and the old hard drive. Install ubuntu via USB if you can or try ANOTHER cdrom/dvdrom with another burned copy. Remove the 8600 video card also. Try like that and let me know. What we are doing here is discarding from the basic parts anything that might be creating the problem. Let me know friend.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an alternative...

Any reason why dual boot? It seems there are issues when people try to create a dual boot. I had similar problems.

In the end, I installed Ubuntu, and run Win7 in VMplayer. Works great and does everything I need it to do, with no issues. However you may have issues if you need specific hardware to run in windows, where Linux does not recognise that hardware.

However I had no issues running any windows software within the VMplayer environment.